# Make sure that dispose method is always called

Tags: c#, idisposable

I've a class called `MyClass` which inherits from `IDisposable`.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    // clean up
    }
}
```

I'm not sure who is going to use my class, but I want to make sure that whoever is using my class must call `Dispose()` method after he is done using `MyClass`.

How can I force the user who is using `MyClass` to call this `Dispose()` method?

Comment: You can't unless using a finalizer. All it does is to give a nice built in way to help people clean after them. (like if putting it in a using clause).

Comment: You've already done your bit - your implementing `IDisposable`. That's the signal to your consumers/various linting tools that to omit the call to `Dispose` is an error.